Flutter Timeline View (example Jira Timeline)
I am developing a booking screen in Flutterda and it will have a timeline of tables linked to hours. So tables on the left as rows, hours on the top as columns. Table data will be tables. It is possible to do this with Synfusion, but the most important feature I want is to be able to expand the time in the calendar if I hold down on the table data (reservation box) and pull it to the right. So for example, while the reservation is between 15:00 - 15:30, I want to be able to hold down and expand it to 15:00-16:00. An example that we can expand on the timeline screen in Jira is exactly what I need.
example image
I tried Synfusion but as far as I look at the examples, unfortunately the drag feature is only for transportation. I need a function to extend or shorten time.
